# how to add a custom entry in UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When i open an attachment from iPhone or iPad mail application, there is a popup that can transfert the file to a third party application.

This iOS popup is called UIActivityViewController.

I wand to add my own iOS application (written in swift) in this popup and i do not know how to do...

Thanks

Comment: Here is a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/)

Comment: Thanks but i do not know which extension type is in relation to UIActivityViewController...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking about two separate things.

**UIActivityViewController:**

Here's my code in my app.

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareImage], applicationActivities: [])
vc.excludedActivityTypes =  [
    UIActivityType.airDrop,
    UIActivityType.assignToContact,
    UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
    //UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
    //UIActivityType.mail,
    //UIActivityType.message,
    //UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
    //UIActivityType.postToFacebook,
    //UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
    UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
    //UIActivityType.postToTwitter,
    UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
    UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
    UIActivityType.print,
    //UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll
]
present(vc,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
vc.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activity, success, items, error) in
}
```

Pay attention to the **excludedActiviyTypes** code. My app is an image effect app, so I commented out the things I wish to have in the popup - Weibo, print, assignToContact, ReadingList, Vimeo, and TencentWeibo. Here's the thing - I kept the full list of activities for quick reference. (I've never found it on ADC and end up getting it by using code complete.)

UIActivityType is an extended struct, so if you want to go the route of using it this way I think you'll have to (1) subclass UIActivityViewController, (2) write your own extension to UIActivityType, and (3) provide any/all code needed to use a service that isn't listed above.

A [Document Provider](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html) is what I think you are looking for. Either that, or [Universal - sometimes called Deep - Linking](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/). (The links are to Apple documentation for using each.)

I've obviously used UIActivityiewController, but haven't (yet) had any need to these other two.

If you have questions about setting up a UIActivityViewController, post them in the comments. If someone else has a way to "extend" it in any way other than I described, let me know and I'll remove this answer.