# Add my app to suggestions of share in Apple Maps

Tags: ios, sharing

On Apple Maps there is a possibility to share given location (left image).
After you tap it, the list of compatible programs shows (right image).

[image: Apple Maps share image] [image: Apple Maps share details image]

What exactly should I support in my app to be able to have my app on this list? Should it be a link or document type? If one of this, exactly what kind?

Comment: I answered this in another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575450/how-to-add-a-custom-entry-in-uiactivityviewcontroller/41577506#41577506). I won't make this a duplicate, because while my answer was accepted, the second part of it was explaining that you *can't* do what you are asking. I threw out some alternatives, but nobody contradicted my bad news. Since I'm not 100% sure you can't do this, I feel I should see if you get a different response.

Comment: @dfd Thank you very much, I didn't find that question when I did the initial research. While I suspect it requires some kind of document type in the plist (or maybe even deep links), I don't know which kind exactly and that's what's this question about. I can't agree you can't add your app to email's share. For example, if email consists an xml file, you just simply add xml to your supported list and you can see your app on the list in the email client. Obviously, you can't open all kinds of files. But that's behind the scope. I don't know what exactly maps here try to share. A link? A text?

Comment: My guess is it's XML, a location (CLLocation?), or an image of some sort. But my main point in that link is UIActivityType is struct if UIKit, and that a developer can only include (by commenting out) those types he/she wants to include. To *add* an app to the list would require both extending UIActivityTYpe and UIActivityTypeController as I see it. My app included clipboard and message sending (SMS) too, but only by commenting out those UIActivityTypes. But it might be interesting to see what AirDrop shares (it's probably Maps specific).

Comment: I guess it gets back to something I learned a long time ago - what I call the "show me" rule. If you can point out to me an app (Apple or third party) that has a share that *is not* in that UIActivityType list, I'll stick to my statement that it cannot be done. (I used to support SAP and my favorite example involves a so-called experience person asking me to use "red text" in the SAPgui. She couldn't give me an example. I did come up with some magic though - embedded some HTML with an "error background" that meant a red background.)

Comment: @dfd I'm not sure if we follow each other correctly. You can add your app to the list of possible "openers". For example, if you state your app can open `.xml`, your app will be shown on the list. I don't have to show it to you, just open mail with `.cad` file and if you have AutoCad installed - it will be visible on the list. Here it is the same, but I have no idea what type of file (or what link) does the map try to open. Because of this, I cannot state my app supports it. You can clearly see on the screenshot above, that Pintrest, a 3rd party app, was able to do it.

Comment: And... you "showed me"! I actually thought Pinterest *was* included as a UIActivityType. (My bad.) I think this is the Document Provider or Universal (Deep) Linking I mentioned in the first link I gave here. And yes, I see what you want. Looking at this (https://developer.apple.com/maps/) it could be almost anything. I apologize for the confusion.